# Chaining ASYNC tasks within tasks in cmd application causes crash without exception

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Edit:
here is my main method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    LogNewOrders();
    DataTable initialData = ControllerSqlAgent.SelectQuery(Resources.Controller, Resources.qryGetInitalData);
    Console.WriteLine($"|There are {initialData.Rows.Count} orders to check|");
    Task.WhenAll(UpdateItemCountsField(initialData));
}
```

I have a method called `UpdateItemCountsField(datatable)`

The purpose of this method is to get both:

- total cancelled items
- total shipped items

  ```
  private static async Task UpdateItemCountsField(DataTable initialData)
  {
      try
      {
          foreach (DataRow row in initialData.Rows)
          {
              string narvarId = row["NarvarID"].ToString();
              int orderedItemCount = (int)row["ItemsOrdered"];
              int totalShippedItems = (int)row["ItemsShipped"]; ;
              int totalCancelledItems = (int)row["ItemsCancelled"];
              string locateConstraint = GetLocateInConstraint(row["OrderNumber"].ToString(), row["CompanyNumber"].ToString());
              Task<int> totalShippedItemsTask = CheckShipmentCountsAsync(locateConstraint, row["OrderNumber"].ToString(), row["CompanyNumber"].ToString(), totalShippedItems, narvarId);
              Task<int> totalCancelledItemsTask = CheckCancellationCountsAsync(locateConstraint, row["OrderNumber"].ToString(), row["CompanyNumber"].ToString(), totalCancelledItems, narvarId); ;
              int[] result = await Task.WhenAll(totalShippedItemsTask, totalCancelledItemsTask);
              //totalShippedItems = CheckShipmentCounts(locateConstraint, row["OrderNumber"].ToString(), row["CompanyNumber"].ToString(), totalShippedItems, narvarId);
              //totalCancelledItems = CheckCancellationCounts(locateConstraint, row["OrderNumber"].ToString(), row["CompanyNumber"].ToString(), totalCancelledItems, narvarId);
              Console.WriteLine($"|ID:{narvarId}|Ordered: {orderedItemCount}|Shipped: {result[0]}|Cancelled: {result[1]}|");
              Console.WriteLine("|___________________________________________|");
          }
      }
      catch
      {
          throw;
      }
  }
  ```

I have two Task objects that I obtain from async methods:

```
Task<int> totalShippedItemsTask = CheckShipmentCountsAsync(params);
Task<int> totalCancelledItemsTask = CheckCancellationCountsAsync(params);
```

Then i get my results like so (this is where the program crashes)

```
int[] result = await Task.WhenAll(totalShippedItemsTask,totalCancelledItemsTask);
```

within `CheckShipmentCoutnsAsync(params)` and `CheckCancellationCountsAsync(params)` are two more `Task<int>` objects . This is due to there being two data sources that i have to pull from

```
   private static async Task<int> CheckShipmentCountsAsync(string locateConstraint, string orderNumber, string companyNumber, int currentShippedItemCount, string narvarId)
    {
        Task<int> wmsShippedCountTask = WmsSqlAgent.GetCountOfShippedItemsAsync(orderNumber, companyNumber);
        Task<int> locateShippedCountTask = LocateSqlAgent.GetCountOfShippedItemsAsync(locateConstraint);
        int[] result = await Task.WhenAll(wmsShippedCountTask, locateShippedCountTask);
        int newShippedItemCount = result.Sum();
        if (newShippedItemCount > currentShippedItemCount)
            ControllerSqlAgent.UpdateShippedItemCount(narvarId, newShippedItemCount);
        return newShippedItemCount;
    }
```

The method `CheckCancelCountsAsync(PARAMS)` is the same as the above but for cancellations.

When my program runs, It hits the task and then crashes without any exception and never reaches the  next datarow to perform the asynchronous methods on. Am I missing a piece here? Why would my application crash without an exception. the reason I believe it is crashing due to the fact that it never makes it to the Console.Writeline(); right after i get the result array from `Task.WhenAll`

And here is the data source method that retrieves the actual count

```
internal static async Task<int> GetCountOfCancelledItemsAsync(string orderNumber, string companyNumber)
{
    int itemCount = 0;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Resources.WMS))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (var command = new SqlCommand(Resources.qryWmsGetCancelledItemCount, connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderNumber", orderNumber);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyNumber", companyNumber);
                    itemCount = int.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
                }

                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException E)
        {
            string message = E.Message;
            throw;
        }
        return itemCount;
    });
    return itemCount;
```

While stepping through the code I can see that my program crashes when i get to `nt[] result = await Task.WhenAll(totalShippedItemsTask, totalCancelledItemsTask);` but still no exception.

Comment: What calls `UpdateItemCountsField`, and what does that call look like? `async void`methods create some problems with exceptions and should generally be avoided; see https://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/.

Comment: static void main() calls UpdateItemCountsField does this need to be a task?

Comment: What does "crash" mean in this context? Do you get a specific error message? Please update your question with more details.

Comment: That's the issue there is no error.. It says the program has exited with code 0 which provides me no context to give. The program just shuts down.  I have tried changing `async void` to `async task` still same issue when I call `Task.WhenAll(method)) but still no luck

Comment: You haven't actually shown the line of code in your main method that calls `UpdateItemCountsField`. That's necessary to have a [MCVE].

Comment: I have added it. I was trying to keep it minimal because well it says minimal and it was just the one liner.

Comment: Minimal means no more code than necessary. Even one line of code can be necessary. Another component of MCVE is Complete. If the error isn't in the code in your question, then that makes it much more difficult to spot what's wrong. Ideally you would provide us with a piece of code we could drop into a .NET console app and get the same exact results as you.

Comment: So now that you've shown the code from your main method, I don't see you actually awaiting the results of your Task.WhenAll call. You need to await the result of that. Make sure you're on C# 7.1 or later, mark your Main method as async, and have it return a Task instead of void. Then change it to `await Task.WhenAll(UpdateItemCountsField(initialData));` and see what happens

Comment: You need to await ALL of your tasks. You missed one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not awaited the results of `Task.WhenAll(UpdateItemCountsField(initialData))` in your main method. This means that the program will exit without waiting for that code to finish executing.

Change your method to this:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    LogNewOrders();
    DataTable initialData = ControllerSqlAgent.SelectQuery(Resources.Controller, Resources.qryGetInitalData);
    Console.WriteLine($"|There are {initialData.Rows.Count} orders to check|");
    await UpdateItemCountsField(initialData);
}
```

Since UpdateItemCountsField returns a single Task, the Task.WhenAll wrapping it was redundant, so I removed that from the code in my answer.

Note that you [must be using C# 7.1](https://www.meziantou.net/2017/08/24/4-ways-to-enable-the-latest-c-features) or later in order to have an async main method.

Make sure on any method that returns a Task that you `await` the result.

Comment: So basically every method involving async will have Task<T> as the return value, and in order to execute that Task and return a value, they all have to have an await to activate it. It seems to get very redundant but this looks like it did the trick and at first glance it looks like it is running a bit faster than the syncronous way I was doing it before. Thanks again.

Comment: @boo No, awaiting it doesn't activate the task. The task generally will start running as soon as created. However, you won't get the result of that task until it is awaited. So if you had some other work to do that doesn't depend on that asynchronous work being done, you might want to do that before you `await` the result. Also, you should keep in mind that since `UpdateItemCountsField` is just returning a single Task, there's actually no need for Task.WhenAll. You could just do `await UpdateItemCountsField(initialData);`